# Is this species a variant of a red flour beetle?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

Found this little guy crawling around the back garden - South Coast of the UK.

[image: First shot]

[image: Second shot]

The closest things I could find online (with an admittedly weak knowledge of where to look up these things, aside a google search for `red beetle`) were the [red flour beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_flour_beetle). However, it doesn't look quite like what we had, this being more stockier, with a dark head, and more splayed feelers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not look like a red flour beetle, but more like some species of [*Melolontha*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melolontha), possibly a [cockchafer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockchafer). For more specific information, we would need to know, where your back garden is and maybe something to scale the bug. I would go for *Melolontha melolontha*, the common cockchafer.
Of the two other european species of *Melolontha*, *M. hippocastani* usually has a black edge of the elytra (see [this](https://artportalen.se/Image/656473) picture), which this one doesn't seem to have, and *M. pectoralis* is very rare and mostly (only?) found in Germany.

Comment: I've added some location information - meant to in the original post, but forgot! But I'm on the south coast of the UK

Comment: Then it is from my understanding perfectly normal environment for a Melolontha melolontha.

Comment: *M. hippocastani* usually has a black edge of the elytra (which this one doesn't seem to have), which makes *M. melolontha* even more likely. *M. pectoralis* is very rare and mostly (only?) found in Germany. I've added this info to your answer and hope you are fine with this.

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree with skymningen, definitely a [cockchafer](http://www.uksafari.com/cockchafer.htm)

[image: cockchafer]